# How to validate if the logged user is in present in list of userids in properties file

Tags: java, string, validation, servlets, string-comparison

I have mentioned a multiple user ids in external properties file (eg: userId=ab123c, bv111y,…). I want to validate the logged user with this list and allow access to certain jsp, if the logged user’s id matches the id mentioned in properties file. I figured out how to validate when there is only one userId in properties file. Not sure how to dod it with multiple users. I am new to development and coding so I request you to explain me what needs to be done in detail.

Code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String userAttuid = (String)myApp.properties.getProperty(“userId”);

String loggedUser = (String)request.getAttribute(“attuid”);

//I need help here to validate for multiple users 
// I have written code for one user 

If(loggedUser.equalsIgnoreCase(userAttuid) {

forwardToClient(“/Settings.jsp”,request,response);
}
else {

throw new exception();//any suitable exception

}
```

Your help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what your properties file looks like? Specifically, what the "userId" property should return/

Answer (score 0):

You can always, read the user ids, split them and keep it as a list.
See an approach below:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userAttUids = (String)myApp.properties.getProperty(“userId”);
    // Split configured IDs to a list
    List<String> userAttrIds = Arrays.asList(userAttUids.toLowerCase().split(","))

    String loggedUser = (String)request.getAttribute(“attuid”);
    //check if the user id is present in the list
    if(userAttrIds.contains(loggedUser.toLowerCase())) {

        forwardToClient(“/Settings.jsp”,request,response);
    }
    else {

        throw new exception();//any suitable exception

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and I am getting an error “Invalid expression as statement” in the line: List<String> userAttrIds = Arrays.asList(userAttuids.toLowerCase().split(“,”));